# Eligibility for stock rights offering

Tags: stocks

Lets say company X announces on September 22nd (before market opens) that all stockholders as of that date have the right to purchase additional shares at a discount. Does it makes sense to become a **new stockholder** on that day (assuming the price will go up in the future) in order to be able to participate in the offering ? Is there a delay between when the stock is bought and when new stockholders appear on the company stockholder list ?

Comment: This seems very, very hypothetical. Is this a situation you are facing? Has this ever happened?

Comment: Usually the announcement is made in advance or after the fact. The same day announcement is a made-up detail to make the question easier to answer if there is indeed a delay in updating the stockholder list.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a delay between when you buy a stock and when you actually take ownership of it.  This is called the **[settlement period](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/settlement_period.asp)**.

The settlement period for US equities is `T+2` (other markets have different settlement periods), meaning you don't actually become a shareholder of record until 2 business days after you buy.  Conversely, you don't *stop* being a shareholder of record until 2 business days after you sell.

Presumably at some point in the (far) future all public markets will move to same-day changes of ownership, at which point companies will stop making announcements of the form

> all shareholders of record as of September 22nd

and will switch to announcements of the form

> all shareholders of record as of September 22nd at 13:00 UTC